# How to disable combobox so that assign him null \ return the previous value when enabled?

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, combobox

In the Form a table(datagrid), combobox's, button "add" and checkbox. Combobox get value from the database. Select something from a list of combobox's, click "add", the data is transferred to the table. Checkbox enables and disables one of combobox's, but the data is still passed in spite of the state of activity. Button to add a SQL query executes with parameters, each parameter respectively, equal to it's combobox's. How to make the combobox when you disable its value has been passed is null, so that one of the columns of table when you click "add" just remained empty, and when you enable it get data of DataSource?

I did this:

```
     SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();

     param1.ParameterName = "@name";


            if (ComboBox1.Enabled == true)
            {

                param1.Value = ComboBox1.Text;
                param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Text;
            }
            else
            {

                param1.Value = " ";
                param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Text;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the click event of your Add button, you can check to see if the combo box is disabled or not. If it is disabled, set the parameter for that combo box to null.

Comment: if (p_bookComboBox.Enabled == false)
            {
                param7.Value = null;
            }
the same...

Comment: Could you post the exception message that you get?

Comment: No any exceptions, just a string is added.

Answer (score 1):

Handle [CheckBox.CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged) event for the disable checkbox and set [ComboBox.SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue) to null.

Comment: private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                p_bookComboBox.Enabled = false;
                p_bookComboBox.SelectedValue = null;
            }
            else
                p_bookComboBox.Enabled = true;
        }
exception: value can not be null

Comment: What is the DataSource and ValueMember for combobox?

Comment: Perhaps try `SelectedIndex = 0`  to un-select combobox

Comment: ValueMember = "ID"(null is not allowed)